# JavaFx multi lines tab title

Tags: javafx

I have long titles for tab pane tabs. Please, help me to make tabs titles to contain more than one line.

```
public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Stage stage = new Stage();

        Tab tab1 = new Tab("tab1 tab1 tab1 tab1 tab1 ");
        Tab tab2 = new Tab("tab2 tab2 tab2 tab2 tab2 ");
        Tab tab3 = new Tab("tab3 tab3 tab3 tab3 tab3 ");
        TabPane tabPane = new TabPane(tab1, tab2, tab3);

        tabPane.setMinHeight(80);
        tabPane.setMaxWidth(230);

        HBox hbox = new HBox(10);
        hbox.getChildren().addAll(new Label("Tabs ==> "), tabPane);

        Scene choosePlayer = new Scene(hbox, 300, 400);
        stage.setScene(choosePlayer);
        stage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Inserting a **\n** should do the trick : new Tab("tab1 tab1 tab1 \n tab1 tab1 ");

Comment: @DmitryKolesnikovich you are right. I use JFoenix. the JFX TabPane allows that. The regular sadly not

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Tab;
import javafx.scene.control.TabPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Stage stage = new Stage();

        Tab tab1 = new Tab("tab1 tab1 tab1\ntab1 tab1");
        Tab tab2 = new Tab("tab2 tab2 tab2\ntab2 tab2 ");
        Tab tab3 = new Tab("tab3 tab3 tab3\ntab3 tab3 ");
        TabPane tabPane = new TabPane(tab1, tab2, tab3);

        HBox hbox = new HBox(10);
        hbox.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("Main.css").toExternalForm());
        hbox.getChildren().addAll(tabPane);

        Scene choosePlayer = new Scene(hbox);
        stage.setScene(choosePlayer);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Main.css

```
.tab-pane {
    -fx-tab-min-height: 70;
    -fx-tab-max-height: 70;
}
```

---

[image]

Comment: How did you do this? I created file stylesheet.css and added the line   scene.getStylesheets().add("stylesheet.css"); But this had no effect

Comment: Copy `Main.java` and `Main.css`, put both on the same directory and run.

Comment: I did this and there was no effect. Could you send me your project? May be it's a version problem?

Comment: Maybe someone here will test it and post his / her results